# Archive the file in adf with timestamp using copy activity in adf

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

My requirement is to Copy specific file based on wild card from a container/folder in datalake to azure database using copy activity and then copy the file into a different folder with timestamp at the end of the file.

I used getmetadata and filter activities to get the specific file name from the datalake/blob folder to be loaded.But copy activities to database and the file movement with timestamp are failing.

Please find the attachment for the steps that was followed.
Can you please help.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/oksirsemouysoze0pobtb/archive-file-with-timestamp-in-adf.docx?dl=0&rlkey=lt4nypgeqtozzvpikbxme102w

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this. After filter activity used foreach activity and inside that used setvariable. Using this setvariable able to archive the source file with timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

In your copy activity, for sink, create a variable "Archive_fileName". Once this file show on sink, set the value using to this

@concat(replace(item().Name,'.txt',''),'_',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMdd'),'_archived.txt')

Change file extension to your file type ( Here txt is file extension in this example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).